# Optimizers with moment in custom training loop

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

If I am creating a personal training loop from scratch, does the Adam optimizer will apply correctly?

I doubt this because the optimizer is applied manually at each batch. No lines tell the program to remember the previous gradients. I wonder whether in this case Adam degenerates to a simple one-step gradient descent method.

Here is the example codes adapted from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch. I simply change their SGD optimizer to Adam

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation.
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Prepare the training dataset.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Prepare the validation dataset.
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

Comment: The Adam implementation takes care of it - changing SGD to Adam (with any relevant parameter changes) is all that's required from your side.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Hey thank you for the response. That memory is amazing! Hope in the future they can clarify this in their official guide.